# Displaying all native paths for the shared Library

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, websphere, jython

I want to access the shared library native paths using jython scripts

```
libraries = AdminConfig.list('Library').split('\n')
```

this returns a list of libraries.

In libraries.xml

```
<libraries:Library xmi:id="Library_1443450998699" name="MY_TOOLKIT" description="AMY_TOOLKIT" isolatedClassLoader="false">
    <classPath>MY_TOOLKIT</classPath>
    <nativePath>/mypath_TOOLKIT/lib/path.jar</nativePath>
```

I want to access each library's native paths..

How can I achieve this .... Any Help.. thanks in advance

Comment: look into XML data scraping, which is a pretty simple, built in process for python. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python might help a bit. you can also use regex, which would be even more simple

Comment: @RNar Directly accessing the XML configuration of WebSphere Application Server might work, but it's not recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the values returned from `list`/`split` and use `AdminConfig.showAttribute(lib, "nativePath")`.  See the [Commands for the AdminConfig object using wsadmin scripting](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/rxml_adminconfig1.html) topic in the Knowledge Center for other AdminConfig operations.